# protoc shared libraries error in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: c++, linux, caffe

I tried to install caffe in Ubuntu 16.04 and I encountered the error when I typed `make all` in the root caffe directory.

```
protoc: error while loading shared libraries: libprotoc.so.9: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I tried `protoc --version`, the error is still:

```
protoc: error while loading shared libraries: libprotoc.so.9: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

So I used `locate libprotoc.so.9`, and found that the libprotoc exists in

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotoc.so.9
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotoc.so.9.0.1
```

So I used the following methods try to let system knows where is libprotoc,

1)

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib
```

2) go to `/etc` and add the path by

```
vim ld.so.conf
```

Although I used `sudo ldconfig` everytime I made any change to the files, still the error exists. I also found that when I tried `gedit filename`, the similar error will show up as :

```
gedit: error while loading shared libraries: libmirprotobuf.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I really don't know how to deal with this shared libraries problem.

And idea would be helpful !

**UPDATE:**
so I remove the original protobuf by `sudo uninstall protobuf`,however a new error shows up when I use `make all` in caffe file,

```
.build_release/src/caffe/proto/caffe.pb.h:10:40: fatal error: google/protobuf/port_def.inc: No such file or directory
```

And `port_def.inc` actually exists at `~/google/protobuf/port_def.inc`.Seems I cannot let caffe know the path, that's the problem.

But how to solve it ?